# Error while converting raster into vector in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, vectorization

I am using QGIS 2.18.23 and trying to convert a raster file (.tif) into a vector file (.shp). But I am getting an unusual error:

> 2018-08-28T12:41:38   1   Traceback (most recent call last):
>               File "D:/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\widgetPluginBase.py",
>   line 88, in onFinished
>                 self.base.onFinished(exitCode, status)
>               File "D:/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\dialogBase.py",
>   line 208, in onFinished
>                 msg = unicode(self.process.readAllStandardError())          UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position
>   463: invalid continuation byte

I thought it was because the location directory of my files was in Cyrillic (Russian) but I changed that and it still showing the same error.

Comment: have you tried to check this article [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 13: invalid continuation byte](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags/issues/194)? Your data has to be in UTF-8.